# writing function in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have just started to learn python and don't have much of dev background. Here is the code I have written while learning.

I now want to make a function which exactly does what my "for" loop is doing but it needs to calculate different exp(exp,exp1 etc) based on different num(num, num1 etc)

how can I do this?

```
import pandas as pd
index = [0,1]
s = pd.Series(['a','b'],index= index)
t = pd.Series([1,2],index= index)
t1 = pd.Series([3,4],index= index)
df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns = ["str"])
df["num"] =t
df['num1']=t1

print (df)

exp=[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['str'] == 'a'):
        row['mul'] = -1 * row['num'] 
        exp.append(row['mul'])
    else:
        row['mul'] = 1 * row['num'] 
        exp.append(row['mul'])
df['exp'] = exp

print (df)
```

This is what i was trying to do which gives wrong results

```
import pandas as pd
index = [0,1]
s = pd.Series(['a','b'],index= index)
t = pd.Series([1,2],index= index)
t1 = pd.Series([3,4],index= index)
df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns = ["str"])
df["num"] =t
df['num1']=t1

def f(x):
    exp=[]

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if(row['str'] == 'a'):
            row['mul'] = -1 * x
            exp.append(row['mul'])
        else:
            row['mul'] = 1 * x 
            exp.append(row['mul'])
    return exp

df['exp'] = df['num'].apply(f)
df['exp1'] = df['num1'].apply(f)
df
```

Per suggestion below, I would do:

```
df['exp']=np.where(df.str=='a',df['num']*-1,df['num']*1)
df['exp1']=np.where(df.str=='a',df['num1']*-1,df['num1']*1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `np.where`

```
df['exp']=np.where(df.str=='a',df['num']*-1,df['num']*1)
df
Out[281]: 
  str  num  num1  exp
0   a    1     3   -1
1   b    2     4    2
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see how np.where does same thing efficiently what for/if/else was doing. What i actually want to do is make this a function which can accept different values for num and generate different exp.  So, in this example, num, num1 should be input to function and result should add exp, exp1 to df

Comment: I updated the question. I was trying to use function but i think do the same with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Normal dataframe operation:

```
df["exp"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["num"] * (1 if x["str"]=="a" else -1), axis=1)
```

Mathematical dataframe operation:

```
df["exp"] = ((df["str"] == 'a')-0.5) * 2 * df["num"]
```